# Django non unique username field warning

Tags: python, django

In my django app I have a custom user model with a username field called `my_username`. Recently I made this field non unique (actually it is now `unique_together` with another field). This makes django to emit the following warning in `manage.py`:

> (auth.W004) 'MyUser.my_username' is named as the 'USERNAME_FIELD', but it is not unique.
>   HINT: Ensure that your authentication backend(s) can handle non-unique usernames.

Is there a way to prevent this warning for displaying? I only found ways to disable all warnings, but I want to disable only that specific one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Django 1.7, there is a setting to silence certain warnings. If you are using Django 1.7 or later, you can add the error code to the `SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS` setting:

```
# settings.py

SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ["auth.W004"]
```

source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#silenced-system-checks